# UIView to Editable PDF. Possible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, pdf, uiview

I am trying to convert a UIView to pdf (iOS). I managed to do it by using renderInContext. However, it captures the whole UIView as an "image" which is not really what I want. The questions and answers I found on stackoverflow gives me the same result of using the renderInContext.

I want to convert the whole UIView (with my textfields etc.) to editable pdf. Which means the pdf file after converting still enables the user to edit what was already written in the textfields in the pdf (the pdf file will be sent to email and edited in the computer).

Is this possible? If so, how can I go about doing this?